# Power BI - calculated column that counts rows in the same table and does not ignore slicers

Tags: powerbi

I have a table that has columns:

```
Year, Month, Datetime, Action, CustomerId
```

I use `Year` and `Month` in slicers for the table.

I need a calculated column that counts all rows that have `CustomerId` and `Action = CustomerId` and `Action` in the current row.

In SQL I would do this with

```
SELECT COUNT(Action) OVER(PARTITION BY...)
```

Why are filters from slicers are ignored when I just do

```
calcColumn = countrows(mytable)
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Some sample data and expected result would make this much easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

A calculated column cannot be affected by slicers since they are evaluated only once each time the queries are updated.

If you want something responsive to filters, then you need to use measures instead.

Here's a pretty good summary article distinguishing the two:

http://radacad.com/measure-vs-calculated-column-the-mysterious-question-not

Comment: I can't find a way to do this with a measure. In a new table I can use 

SUMMARIZE (
 'Action'; 'Action'[CustId];'Action'[Month];
 "Anzahl" ;COUNT ( 'Action'[ID] )
)
How can I do something like that in a measure for a table visual?

Comment: What fields do you have on the rows and/or columns of your table visual?

Comment: now I have all fields of the table in the table visual. I have an Excel solution that needs to be ported to PBI. In this Excel the cells use the CountIF Function to lookup the table an count all rows that have CustID and Action = CustId and Action in current row